# ipad touch animation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cabasicanimation

Im having trouble animating a wheel using touch. Ive spent some time punching in different numbers values for duration, spin times and animation durations to get a smooth move using on thouchsMove, but every time a touch happens the wheel rotates and what seems to be happening is it jumps back to its original position. If any one can shed some light on this i would very much appreciate it.

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.delegate = self; 

rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2  * 1 * 45 ];
rotationAnimation.duration = 2;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1; 


rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];


[animatedImage.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the reset. Can you tell us if there are any gesture recognizers or touch handling associated with `animatedImage`?

Comment: hi, im not sure i understand, i am calling the above method from - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

Comment: So you start this animation on a touch and then after the animation is over, is it returning to its original position?

Comment: no exactly, the animation is being called while you remain on touch. For example, imagine a music turn table, and you are moving the LP with your finger up and down. I want to create the same effect by moving my uiimageview in a circular movement withut lifting my finger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having the same problem follow this example, its spot on. 
http://ericmcconkie.com/2010/03/trig-and-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

for those interested code below is whats needed to get the desired effect

```
CGAffineTransform transforms = CGAffineTransformConcat(animatedImage.transform,CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2));
animatedImage.transform = transforms;
```